# How to use nth-child with only direct children?

Tags: html, css

I have this the html below and in my CSS I write `.CommentSection :nth-child(5n)`

Instead of every 5th comment box being changed li .Hide is being changed an other elements. How do I make it so **only** the direct children (always `div class="comment"`) are counted and applied to and not counting its children?

```
<div class="CommentSection">
  <div class="comment" id="c19">
    <ul>
        <li class="username">a</li>
        <li class="date">3/2/2010 6:14:51 AM</li>
        <li class="link"><a href="http://localhost:1223/u/a#c19">Permalink</a></li>
        <li class="flag">Flag</li>
        <li class="Hide"><a href="http://localhost:1223/u?hide=1&amp;t=8&amp;c=19&amp;ret=/u/a">Hide</a></li>
        <li class="delete">Delete</li>
        <li class="reply">Reply</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="text">
      <p>asd</p>
    </div>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.CommentSection > :nth-child(5n)` or `.CommentSection .comment:nth-child(5n)`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
.CommentSection > div.comment:nth-child(5n)
```

This will select every 5th `DIV` with the class *comment* that is a direct child of *CommentSection*.

Comment: Really Alex Gyoshev? Can you cite a source?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.CommentSection .comment:nth-child(5n){
  […]
}
```

Or more specific:

```
.CommentSection > .comment:nth-child(5n) {
  […]
}
```

This should work fine as well:

```
.CommentSection > :nth-child(5n) {
  […]
}
```